# calculating the mean / average between 2 values of one Elasticsearch document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index

```
"test_data": {
"properties": {
   "id": {
      "type": "keyword"
   },
   "value1": {
      "type": "double"
   },
   "value2": {
      "type": "double"
   }
 }
}
```

I'm wondering how calculating the average value between value1 and value2 in a new field value3 with Elasticsearch